# Javascript Repeating Append Textarea Values issue

Tags: javascript, append

I have created a form with four textareas and a submit button. The reason of this form, is when I press the submit button to append the value (text) that i have insert in my textareas inside a div.

When I press the submit button i can see the text that I have insert in my four textareas however when I press the submit button again it will append another four textareas and so on.

What I would like to happen is whenever I press the submit button to just show four textareas(with the updated text) without appending another four textareas.

```js
var firstContent = document.getElementById("first-content");
var secondContent = document.getElementById("second-content");
var thirdContent = document.getElementById("third-content");
var fourthContent = document.getElementById("fourth-content");
var customContainer = document.getElementById("c-content");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("c-btn");


function submitCustomForm() {

  var cElementOne = document.createElement("p");
  cElementOne.innerHTML = firstContent.value;
  customContainer.append(cElementOne);

  var cElementTwo = document.createElement("p");
  cElementTwo.innerHTML = secondContent.value;
  customContainer.append(cElementTwo);

  var cElementThree = document.createElement("p");
  cElementThree.innerHTML = thirdContent.value;
  customContainer.append(cElementThree);

  var cElementFour = document.createElement("p");
  cElementFour.innerHTML = fourthContent.value;
  customContainer.append(cElementFour);
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitCustomForm);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>First Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="first-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Second Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="second-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Third Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="third-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Fourth Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="fourth-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>


    <button id="c-btn">Submit</button>

    <div id="c-content">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the button to be `type="button"` too

Comment: what do you mean by show four textareas with updated text??

Comment: I mean when i change the text of any of the textareas to update and to show four textareas only with the latest text that i have insert in them

Comment: a simple solution could be empty your parent before appending anything to it and append the latest result to it.. something like customContainer.innerHTML=""; in you submitCustomForm() function

Comment: Can u please provide me the code for that based on my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var customContainer = document.getElementById("c-content");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("c-btn");


function submitCustomForm() {
  //clear the content
  customContainer.innerHTML = "";
  var txtid = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
  for (var i = 0; i < txtid.length; i++) {
    appendtxt("" + txtid[i] + "-content", customContainer);
  }

}

function appendtxt(content, parent) {
  var contentvalue = document.getElementById("" + content + "").value;
  if (contentvalue.length > 0) {
    var htmltxt = document.createElement("p");
    htmltxt.innerHTML = contentvalue;
    parent.append(htmltxt);

  }

}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitCustomForm);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>First Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="first-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Second Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="second-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Third Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="third-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Fourth Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="fourth-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>


    <button id="c-btn">Submit</button>

    <div id="c-content">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: year but that is a waste of element creation

Answer (score 1):

With every call of `submitCustomForm()` you are creating new `p` elements. So you are inserting new elements instead of updating the old ones.

You can try something like this:

```js
var customContainer = document.getElementById("c-content");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("c-btn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitCustomForm);

var cElements = [null, null, null, null];
var cContents = [
        document.getElementById("first-content"),
        document.getElementById("second-content"),
        document.getElementById("third-content"),
        document.getElementById("fourth-content")
];

function getElement(no) {
    if (cElements[no]==null) {
        cElements[no] = document.createElement("p");
        customContainer.append(cElements[no]);
    }
    return cElements[no];
}

function submitCustomForm() {
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        var cElement = getElement(i);
        cElement.innerHTML = cContents[i].value;        
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>First Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="first-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Second Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="second-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Third Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="third-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="content-container">
      <label>Fourth Content
        <label>
          <textarea id="fourth-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
    </div>


    <button id="c-btn">Submit</button>

    <div id="c-content">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have tried the code above but it;s not working

Comment: Now you need to make the firstcontent, secondcontent and so on an array too :)

Comment: @mplungjan I know, but I want to stay in the same nomenclature of the example

Comment: Sure - but you were creating the more elegant version anyway :)

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks - but doesn't seem to pay off ;-)

Comment: @mplungjan Couldn't resist - the first time I created a Stack Snippet :)